# android app gives error in registration

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I am in the process of developing a registration app using Android Studios, however once users try to register the application just says error in registration and the LogCat does not give any errors.

User data gets entered into the database however it does not allow the user to move onto the next activity as it says "Error occurred in registration". Please can you help or advise?

when debugging the application further I have found that username is returning a null value, whereas all the other fields such as, fname, sname, email and password are giving a value. Could you please tell me why username is returning a null value rather than a value.

LogCat

```
{"tag":"register","success":1,"error":0,"user":{"fname":"Cat","lname":"Slater","email":"catslater@btinternet.com","uname":"catslater","uid":"569e1fc18103c2.33284778","created_at":"2016-01-19 11:36:33"}}
01-19 11:32:25.470 24404-24418/? E/Buffer Error: Error converting result org.json.JSONException: Value 2016-01-19 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Register.Java

```
 UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname, password);

        return json;


    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");


                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                    /**
                     * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
                     **/

                    UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                    logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                    /**
                     * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                     * Launch Registered screen
                     **/

                    Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registered.class);

                    /**
                     * Close all views before launching Registered screen
                     **/
                    registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    startActivity(registered);


                    finish();
                }

                else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                }
                else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                }

            }


            else{
                pDialog.dismiss();

                registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occurred in registration");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }}
public void NetAsync(View view){
    new NetCheck().execute();
}}
```

UserFunction.Java

```
//URL of the PHP API

    private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/Register_api/";

private static String register_tag = "register";

    /**
         * Function to  Register
         **/
        public JSONObject registerUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String uname, String password){
            // Building Parameters
            List params = new ArrayList();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL,params);
            return json;
        }
```

DatabaseHandler.Java

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cloud_contacts";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static final String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String uname, String uid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, fname); // FirstName
        values.put(KEY_LASTNAME, lname); // LastName
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_USERNAME, uname); // UserName
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("fname", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("lname", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("uname", cursor.getString(4));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(5));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(6));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }






    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }


    /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

I have debugged this by adding break points and using the debugger in Android Studios, which shows that username field is not giving a value. could you please help me and how can I make username give a value rather than giving nothing.

Debugger results.

```
Firstname Value

 result = {EditText@831697172568} "android.widget.EditText{5281dc2c VFED..CL ........ 48,498-1032,642 #7f0c00b9 app:id/fname}"
 mTransformed = {ReplacementTransformationMethod$SpannedReplacementCharSequence@831697185952} "Sam"
  mSpanned = {SpannableStringBuilder@831697185800} "Sam"
 mTransformation = {SingleLineTransformationMethod@831697174928} 
 mText = {SpannableStringBuilder@831697185800} "Sam"
```

Surname Value

```
result = {EditText@831697113576} "android.widget.EditText{528168f4 VFED..CL ........ 48,642-1032,786 #7f0c00ba app:id/lname}"
     mTransformed = {ReplacementTransformationMethod$SpannedReplacementCharSequence@831697116000} "Jones"
      mSpanned = {SpannableStringBuilder@831697115808} "Jones"
     mTransformation = {SingleLineTransformationMethod@831697174928} 
     mText = {SpannableStringBuilder@831697115808} "Jones"
```

Username Value.

```
result = {EditText@831697175208} "android.widget.EditText{5281e154 VFED..CL ........ 48,786-1032,906 #7f0c00bb app:id/uname}"
 mTransformed = {SpannableStringBuilder@831697129800} "joness"
 mTransformation = null
 mText = {SpannableStringBuilder@831697129800} "joness"
```

Email Value.

```
result = {EditText@831697196680} "android.widget.EditText{52820b44 VFED..CL .F...... 48,906-1032,1050 #7f0c0084 app:id/email}"
 mTransformed = {ReplacementTransformationMethod$SpannedReplacementCharSequence@831697200904} "samjones@gmail.com"
  mSpanned = {SpannableStringBuilder@831697200712} "samjones@gmail.com"
 mTransformation = {SingleLineTransformationMethod@831697174928} 
 mText = {SpannableStringBuilder@831697200712} "samjones@gmail.com"
```

Password Value

```
result = {EditText@831697157912} "android.widget.EditText{5281bf8c VFED..CL ........ 48,1050-1032,1194 #7f0c0085 app:id/pword}"
 mTransformed = {PasswordTransformationMethod$PasswordCharSequence@831697164432} "••••••••"
 mTransformation = {PasswordTransformationMethod@831697161672} 
 mText = {SpannableStringBuilder@831697164112} "Password"
```

mTransformation = null Is returning null for usernmae field however for the other fields it is returning a method and value. Please help?.

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18193511/3168859) helps you..

Comment: Can you post your full logcat for the exception you are getting

Comment: I guess the problem is in line where you are adding the result to db that is `db.addUser(...)`

Comment: How you adding `created_at` field in your db?

Comment: It goes into the SQlitehandler. I have posted that file now.