# Can't parse string to JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I have the following string which (as far as I know) is in a valid format

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"John Doe"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Jane Doe"
   }
]
```

After calling the following:

```
return new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

With `jsonString` being the JSON given above. I get the following error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value jsonString of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Any ideas why the parser won't accept the string?

**Edit**

The problem has been solved. The array was encoded as a string in the JSON output. I first retrieved the string with the getString(param) method instead of trying to convert it directly with getJsonArray, then converted the string to the json array.

Comment: How are you representing the JSON in your Java code? In other words, how does it go from the block of JSON you posted, into a `String` variable? I just tried putting your JSON into a `String` and escaping all the quotes, and it worked. Also what version of `org.json.json` are you using?

Comment: Please make sure that you take care of encoding of file, if you are reading json from a file.

Comment: I represent the JSON as a JSON object. The block in the thread is the string value of the key `data`. First, I convert the entire JSON block to a `JSONObject`. After that, I try to get the array under the key `data` by calling `getJSONArray("data")`. The string is escaped correctly.

Comment: Can you add the code you described? As I said, this works for me so I believe something is wrong with how you are extracting the JSON into a `String`.

Comment: The problem is not with the input JSON.  Also, the org.json json jar version 20160810 parses your input without a problem.

Comment: I edited the thread with the full JSON and code, I noticed something though: the array is enclosed with quotes so it's probably interpreted as a string. That's probably the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON appears to be valid on [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/). But a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=java.lang.String%20cannot%20be%20converted%20to%20JSONArray&oq=java.lang.String%20cannot%20be%20converted%20to%20JSONArray&aqs=chrome..69i57.307j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) reveals that there are other possible sources of the problem:

- Are you [specifying UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18194807/5083726) and [decoding the string before parsing it as a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25941890/5083726)?
- Do you need to [add a json library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18193511/5083726) to your project?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. The array was encoded as a string in the full JSON output. I first retrieved the string with the getString(param) method instead of trying to convert it directly with getJsonArray, then converted the string to the json array.