# Android Studio issue with parsing JSON

Tags: java, android, json

When I put the [API](http://api.aladhan.com/timingsByCity?city=Dubai&country=AE&method=2) i try to access into https://jsonlint.com/, it comes out as valid. But when trying to parse it in android studio this is what I get:

**06-23 20:46:54.092 2420-4258/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray**
06-23 20:46:54.093 2420-4258/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
06-23 20:46:54.093 2420-4258/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:96)
06-23 20:46:54.093 2420-4258/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:108)
06-23 20:46:54.093 2420-4258/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at azanmute.android.com.azanmute.MainActivity$SaveTheFeed.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:93)
06-23 20:46:54.093 2420-4258/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at azanmute.android.com.azanmute.MainActivity$SaveTheFeed.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:62)
06-23 20:46:54.094 2420-4258/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
06-23 20:46:54.094 2420-4258/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-23 20:46:54.094 2420-4258/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
06-23 20:46:54.094 2420-4258/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
06-23 20:46:54.094 2420-4258/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
06-23 20:46:54.094 2420-4258/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
06-23 20:46:54.943 2993-3834/com.google.android.gms W/PlatformStatsUtil: Could not retrieve Usage & Diagnostics setting. Giving up.

The line its throwing the error at is:   `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);`

Comment: Can you also post the JSON string that you're trying to parse?

Comment: Is it `{"code":200,"status":"OK","data":{"timings":{"Fajr":"04:18","Sunrise":"05:31","Dhuhr":"12:22","Asr":"15:43","Sunset":"19:12","Maghrib":"19:12","Isha":"20:25","Imsak":"04:08","Midnight":"00:22"},"date":{"readable":"23 Jun 2017","timestamp":"1498243950"}}}`?

Comment: @cosinepenguin Your JSON Is invalid, use a JSON Linter to check for errors - https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: That was the JSON I got from the link in the original question! I was just asking if that was what he was using! Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Yeah thats the one! JSONLint tells me its a valid JSON too

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse your JSON String by:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Comment: No he does not? He's trying to parse a JSON Array, not a JSON Object.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the JSON is validated by the jsonlint service, I believe Android is still considering the JSON string as being in incorrect format! This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174064/value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarray) has some good information about using json-simple, which might help you parse that data:

Essentially, you need to add:

`compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1'`

to your gradle file.

Then, as explained by [Arshu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2660283/arshu),
"Then you can parse your JSON easily and it won't give any error. I have made a small sample code for you on how to use it :

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

JSONParser parser_obj = new JSONParser();
JSONArray array_obj = (JSONArray) parser_obj.parse("String from web service");
```

"

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey!
Using the code you and Gustavo provided (I commented on his what my code looks like right now) I tried to again the jsonString but still get the same error :/ **EDIT: Different error now: 06-23 21:56:40.703 2447-3222/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err: Unexpected character (<) at position 0.**

Answer (score 0):

The `String` that you're trying to parse is a `JSONObject` not a `JSONArray`, so you should do

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

If you really need a `JSONArray`, you can add the `jsonObject` to an array:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The issue is that I had the code print the JSON before the line with the issue and it still gives me the HTML error, but ill be sure to use that thanks!

Comment: I get an error with the put part, 'cannot resolve method put(org.json.JSONOBJECT)

Comment: `jsonString = builder.toString();

                JSONParser parser_obj = new JSONParser();

                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser_obj.parse(jsonString);


                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
                jArray.put(jsonObject);

                Log.d("what", String.valueOf(jsonObject));

                outputTimings(jArray);`

Comment: Sorry for the the late answer. Just now I realize that you are developing to android. I ran here what your code and it work. I changed to match what I said: remove `JSONParser parser_obj = new JSONParser(); JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser_obj.parse(jsonString);` and use just `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);`. It must work. If it doesn't something is wrong and it's not the JSON stuff. Here is the [code and output](http://imgur.com/B7WRjBz). I don't see the need of use JSONParser if JSONObject already converts String directly.