# volley get response returns value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, arrays, api, android-volley

i am trying to authenticate using an api.am getting an error on response, my api returns the following response and am getting the following error.

> value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray.

kindly help, am a newbie.

this is what my api returns:

```xml
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
[{"status":"True","username":"parent","schoolid":"001","category":"3","usercode":"0720994718"}]
</string>
```

this is my code;

```java
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
    //create a StringRequest
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest( Request.Method.GET,
        URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

            int i = 0;
            while (i < jArray.length()) {

                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String status = json_data.getString("status");
            if (status == "True") {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ParentActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "logged in as " + user,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "wrong username or password",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                i++;

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

            },

        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error!!! " + error.toString(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", user);
            params.put("password", pass);
            return params;
        }
    };
    //add the StringRequest to the RequestQueue
    queue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174064/value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarray)

Comment: same not helping, this is what my api returns <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
[{"status":"True","username":"parent","schoolid":"001","category":"3","usercode":"0720994718"}]
</string>

Answer (score 0):

I was change `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);` to `JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);` and `JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);` to `String json_data = jObject(i);`. Try it, please.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
        //create a StringRequest
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest( Request.Method.GET,
           URL,
           new Response.Listener<String>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(String response) {
          try {

               JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);

                int i = 0;
                while (i < jArray.length()) {

                       String json_data = jObject(i);

                      String status = json_data.getString("status");
               if (status == "True") {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ParentActivity.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "logged in as " + user,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                      Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "wrong username or password",
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                  i++;

                     }
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                }

             },

           new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                 Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error!!! " + error.toString(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", user);
                params.put("password", pass);
                return params;
            }
        };
        //add the StringRequest to the RequestQueue
        queue.add(request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your API returning

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
[{"status":"True","username":"parent","schoolid":"001","category":"3","usercode":"0720994718"}]
</string>
```

or

```
[{"status":"True","username":"parent","schoolid":"001","category":"3","usercode":"0720994718"}]
```

?

If the first, then you should extract the JSON string from the XML answer before invoking "JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);", and then do something like "JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json_part_of_the_response);".

Answer (score 0):

I think your JSON array is inside XML so you have to parse your XML first using dom parser